# GTA IV and black screen on Steam

Tags: steam, grand-theft-auto-iv

Each time I start GTA IV in Steam I just get a black screen.

My graphics card is a GTX 1070 with 3 GB RAM, and I have found [this thread](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/200145206-Issues-with-GTA-IV-showing-video-cards-with-over-2GB-as-under-spec), which mentions the solution to set the following parameters to the game shortcut in Steam:

```
-nomemrestrict -norestrictions
```

but this doesn't do anything.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: GTA 4 uses Games for Windows Live. It's a piece of garbage. That's probably what's giving you the black screen.

Comment: yeah well right now I have bought a game that does not work :-(

Comment: It happens.  If you bought it recently get a refund.  It's a giant pain in the butt to run the game on modern OS.

Comment: I have gotten this working on my windows 10 machine using launch options and a patch file which ignores some WLive features. I'll make an answer when i get the oppertunery @u123

Answer (score 1):

I have this working on my Windows 10 PC. In order to actually play it, I had to download a file called `xlive.dll` and place that into my GTA IV folder in the '/steamapps' folder for Steam. Searching something along the lines of "GTA IV xlive" might get you that file.

I set some launch options for the game which make it run how I want it too.

```
-nomemrestrict -norestrictions-framelimit 0-noprecache-novblank -availablevidmem 2048.0 -windowed
```

You can try these - the last number can be edited to suit your needs (if you have more or less video memory available).

I'm not sure if the spacing matters. You can try appending spaces into there but I don't think it makes a difference.
Good luck!